# if condition in rows and columns recursive

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, apply

Issue in applying if conditions in Rows and columns of 2 different dataframes.

```
df1

X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
10  12  8   4   6

df2 

class       MARKS
class_1     8
class_2     6
class_3     9
class_4     10
class_5     11
class_6     8
class_7     5
class_8     4
class_9     7
class_10    5
```

expected output:

```
class 1     Y       Y   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
class 2     Y       Y   Y       FALSE   FALSE
class 3     Y       Y   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
class 4     FALSE   Y   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
class 5     FALSE   Y   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
class 6     Y       Y   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
class 7     Y       Y   Y       FALSE   Y
class 8     Y       Y   Y       FALSE   Y
class 9     Y       Y   Y       FALSE   FALSE
class 10    Y       Y   Y       FALSE   Y

formula: =IF($A$2>$I2,"Y")
FOR CLASS 1 - I2 WILL BE CONSTANT
```

eg: where A2 = 10 of df1 and I2 = 8 of df2. If 10 > 8 then print Y, else condition fails and print FALSE.

```
FOR CLASS 2 - I3 WILL BE CONSTANT 
FORMULA =IF($A$2>$I3,"Y")
```

Similary, where B2 = 12 OF DF1 AND I3 = 6 OF df2 so if 12>6 print Y, else condition fails and print FALSE.

```
code i tried: 

df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")
y = df2.MARKS

Res = apply(data[3,],2,function(x)
        if x <= y:
            print("FALSE")
    else: 
        print("Y")
Res

ERROR: 
File "<ipython-input-27-083bd28bed08>", line 2
if x <= y:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`np.less.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.less.html) for a broadcasted comparison of all values from `df1` with `df2`

---

```
a = df1.values.ravel()
b = df2.MARKS.values

pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.less.outer(b, a), 'Y', 'FALSE'), index=df2['class'])
# If you don't really want 'Y' and 'FALSE', replace those values with what you do want
```

```
              0  1      2      3      4
class
class_1       Y  Y  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
class_2       Y  Y      Y  FALSE  FALSE
class_3       Y  Y  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
class_4   FALSE  Y  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
class_5   FALSE  Y  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
class_6       Y  Y  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
class_7       Y  Y      Y  FALSE      Y
class_8       Y  Y      Y  FALSE      Y
class_9       Y  Y      Y  FALSE  FALSE
class_10      Y  Y      Y  FALSE      Y
```